# Can I have sort order of changes preserved?

Tags: tortoisesvn, tortoisegit

When I use tortoisegit or tortoisesvn and commit my latest changes, I always sort the items in the commit dialog in the same way namely reverse last modified order.

Meaning that I click a table column (twice) every time I popup the commit dialog.

Can I have that sort order remembered in the dialog so the next time I commit a change, changes will already be sorted that way?